# User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, oauth, google-api

Why does this User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); throws a NullPointerException? Any idea?

Comment: post the stacktrace pls

Comment: The userService must be null...

Comment: check how (or if) the `userService` is initialized.

Comment: Most likely userService is not initialized.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceImpl.getCurrentUser(UserServiceImpl.java:44)
 com.google.oauthsample.PrintTasksTitlesServlet.doGet(PrintTasksTitlesServlet.java:44)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Please put this exception into your question (using `code` formatting), it will help everybody reading. As other persons have suggested, your object is likely not initialized. Start by checking this possibility, and post your findings if this still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Being logged into other Google services doesn't guarantee that you'll be logged into the App Engine app. Users need to individually log into your application with their Google Account. You'll need to call createLoginUrl. Take a look at the docs here:

[**Check this link for google description**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers.html)

Comment: I'm using this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-authorization-callback-handler